# Help with creating a compound component in Mono for Android

Tags: android, android-widget, xamarin.android

I would like to create a compound component that consists of a TextView (integer only) and two buttons that would be used to make an up/down (increment) button.  I am using Mono for Android (MonoDroid) but no matter what I do I cannot get it to work, I keep getting an error about the java class not being found.

If anyone has any experience with this and can assist I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any details, all I can do is take a blind stab at the answer.

My guess is you've created your own View class in C#, and are trying to reference it in a layout file.  You need to reference it using the Java name and not the C# name.

See this documentation for more:

http://mono-android.net/Documentation/Guides/Using_Custom_Views_in_a_Layout

Comment: Thank you!  I also got a reply via the monodroid mailing list so thanks to gshackles as well viewing his OpenGL sample.  I was using packagename.classname and it should simply be namespace.classname so I'll give it another try!  Many thanks to both.